# two divs with margins on top of each other, only one of them seems to have a margin

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="left bigbox"></div>
<div class="left">
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
</div>
<div class="left tallbox"></div>

.left{float:left}
.bigbox, .smallbox, .tallbox{margin:5px;background:#000;}
.bigbox{width:490px;height:370px;}
.smallbox{width:240px;height:180px;}
.tallbox{width:240px;height:370px;}
```

So the two smallboxes which are on top of each other both have a margin of 5px. So there should be 10px margin between them top and bottom. But for some reason there's only a 5px margin. Anyone any idea why?

http://jsfiddle.net/4JAdx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a margin collapse.  Add a bottom margin on the first .smallbox to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/y8cGe/.

```
.smallbox:first-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: ah! so I've just gone for setting the margins margin:0px 5px 10px 5px; and that gives me what I need - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elements of `display` type `block` (including divs) by default have collapse-able margins

**[more info](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)**

You could use `display:inline-block` or set a larger bottom margin:

```
margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the floats.

Since the two smallboxes are enclosed in a `<div>` that is floated, their margins collapse inside of this `<div>`.